# Firebase signInWithRedirect throws "Unable to process request due to missing initial state" on Firefox

Tags: flutter, firebase, firefox

I am getting this error for Firebase signInWithRedirect on Firefox. The sign in is working in every browsers but Firefox.

"Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO. 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment."

Comment: We've been encountering the same error for months when trying to signing using Firebase auth for twitter. We also followed the [open Firebase issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256) . It's been over two years, and still, no solution has been found.

Comment: I am following the same thread you mentioned. Firebase seems to neglect this smh.

Comment: I have a same error when I trying to sign in with Twitter.

Comment: I have this error too

Answer (score -1):

In my case I turned off my wifi & used mobile data while going through verification process & it worked for me.